# How to mask passwords in TEdit?

Tags: delphi, authentication

I am making login system ,

I succeeded all the way but ,i want a bit more professional ,in my login system ,when user enters password in his password edit box ,i want to convert them as ***** but i want real data what they types to test their authentication and i want to make save this account ,how can i do that

example

[image]

Comment: I you want your software to look more professional too, think to align your component between them

Comment: What do you mean by 'make save this account'? Do you mean you want the machine to remember the username of the last person who logged in, so that a frequent/lone user only need to enter his password? Or are you talking about implementing a user management system from scratch? Do you already have some kind of users/passwords data store somewhere?

Comment: explained in below answer comment please check it mate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your edit box's PasswordChar property to `*`.

This will make it display only asterisks, but the real text is still available to you in the `Text` property.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that - can you explain more? Edit your question and add more detail - or post a new one..

Comment: ok i will explain mate 
I want to set the edit.teext with the details typed there ,that means when i clicked save account and then loged in after that i want to close my app ,when i ran my app again the login system must contain data which is present in editboxes when i clicked save account . 
and  more over my bsskinedit dont have property passwordmasks :( is there any other way to do that without passwordchar ?

Answer (score 1):

Following up your comments in Blorgbeard's accepted answer (really you should edit your question);

1) If all you want to do is to remember the user's username from the last time they logged in, store something in the 'Current User' part of the registry. [About Delphi - storing things in the registry etc](http://delphi.about.com/u/ua/windowsshellapi/application-config-where.htm) and [More about storing in the registry](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/tregistry.htm) might help.

2) If you want to simulate passwordchar in another kind of editbox, then you're probably going to need to hook into the keypress event. You'll want to have some form-variable to store the 'real' password as it's being accumulated by keypresses, and you'll want to change the keypress char to a '*' (or whatever) once you've captured the keypress but before the char goes to the edit box.

I would imagine that either the form keypreview or just the keyup/keydown events would help you get that. You're going to need to watch out for backspace/delete, or the user doing a copy/paste into the edit box.

I suspect there are enough 'edge cases' with this to drive you to distraction - are you sure there's no password masking mechanism in your component?

Comment: thanks for reply mate 

yes my bsskinedit button dont have passwordchar property :(